# java web start security warning

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a web application that downloads a jar file from the web server using java web start. The jar is signed using J2SE security tool. However, I get the security warning "The application digital signature cannot be verified. Do you want to run the application?"
Am I missing something that is causing this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is self-signed you also need to add the certificate into windows certificate store.
If you use a Certificate Authority such as [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/) then you will not have the problem.

[See here for an explanation](http://www.verisign.com/code-signing/information-center/why-sign-your-code/index.html) (from Verisign) on why to sign from them.

Comment: I don't believe that Java Web Start references the windows cert store. Unless you have modified your deployment.properties, it uses the /lib/security/cacerts to verify certs, so you would need to add it to your cacerts keystore to avoid the warnings. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/security.html